# CI should I use defined BASEPATH on model and view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, security

As I understood correctly, in CI for security reasons we must write this line of code

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

on top of every controller pages so as to prevent the page to be run the controller on its own.

However I am wondering is it necessary to write this code on every view and model pages too ? As I have searched through google and stackoverflow, there is no one explaining clearly on the view and model pages.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't necessarily need to do this.

CodeIgniter stock files have this line because it tries to run with almost zero configuration, which often means the user has put everything under the webroot.

But that being said, it doesn't mean your setup should be like that. Quite the opposite - only your index.php file should be accessible via the web, and if you do that, these lines don't matter.

And of course, you could deny access to the framework files via .htaccess rules in Apache or proper `location` blocks under nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is necessary for security concern. It is for disallowing direct access to your `views` & `models` files through browser. If you dont include this any one can access your files via browser and this is a risk.

However you may disallow direct access to your file through `.htaccess` in `application` directory by following code

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always safer to add

```
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

in your **model and view** because if your server does not allow .htaccess or it is overridden the script can be accessed.